# Is this piece of code creating a class object? If that so why using it this way

Tags: c++, object, pointers, new-operator

```
ClassName *name = new ClassName();
```

Is this piece of code above creating an object with name "name" and type "ClassName"?
If it is then why we can't use like this `ClassName name();`?
Why we are using "new" keyword? Is it because of we' re creating it on the heap?

Comment: Do you know, why you use `*`? If you know this, come back and ask the same question again

Comment: `new` is used to specify dynamic allocation. Why you would choose to to use it over automatic allocation is contextual and based on a long list of factors. Your best bet is to look for pre existing information.

Comment: i know its pointers it holds adresses

Comment: So by extension, what does `operator new` do?

Comment: i mean is it creating an object and storing it in name pointer?

Comment: `ClassName name();` this is not an object creation, it's a function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

No. The piece of code is not creating an object with name "name" and type "ClassName".

It is creating and initializing an object with name "name" and type "pointer to ClassName".  The variable "name" will contain the address of a fully-constructed object of type "ClassName".  This is called "constructing an object of dynamic storage duration."

Why construct objects of dynamic storage duration?  The answer is that the other three types of storage duration (automatic, static, thread-local) are inappropriate and it is the best solution for the problem you're trying to solve.